# Selenium Webdriver with PHP - Chrome

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, facebook-php-webdriver

Recently, I am using Firefox with version 35(I have downgraded it) and the combination of **selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar** which is not latest yet.It is working.

I am using Facebook Webdriver with PHP Bindings to run my selenium scripts.
Now If I try to download the latest **selenium server is 3.4** and my current **Chrome version is 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit)**.

Now Anyone can please tell me which Compatibility to use for chrome driver.
I have researched a-lot about this but couldn't find particular piece of information.
As I don't have any code to show in this so I am just providing my research work in this field.
Hope anyone can suggest me with combination.

Answer (score 1):

All the information you need can be found on their download page for chromedriver page.

For Chrome 54, chromedriver version should be under version `2.28`.

Go to the chromedriver page from the seleniumhq download page and you should see a link for `All versions` under the `Latest Release` and from there check changes for each release.

Try to update Chrome browser, or try different chromedriver versions with different selenium server versions starting from the latest versions of both.

Answer (score 0):

After so much of R & D I found and came up with these pair of vesions compatibility.

> use Selenium 2.53.1 server
>
> chrome version >= 58.0.3029.0
>
> ChromeDriver 2.30.477691